# Is there any ways to apply where clause in result of stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have strored procedure that using `union all` in it. It's something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
 @date1  datetime,
 @date2  datetime
AS
BEGIN
 select 'Product 1' as Product, * from tab1 where dateStart = @date1 and dateEnd = @date2 and qty >= 100
 union all
 select 'Product 2' as Product, * from tab2 where dateStart = @date1 and dateEnd = @date2 and qty < 100
END
```

Each table have same `fields` but don't have `Product` as their `field`, it's just a sample from my real procedure. It's gonna too long to write here.

When I'm execute the stored procedure `EXEC sp_test '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01'` It's shown like this

```
Product   | qty
----------------
Product 1 | 120
Product 1 | 178
Product 1 | 250
Product 2 | 75
Product 2 | 50
Product 2 | 23
```

The question is, how can I get the result only `Product 1` from stored procedure `sp_test`?

Technically, I want to show the result in crystal report using vb.net, I've try this in vb.net

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal date1 As DateTime, ByVal date2 As DateTime) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            oConn.Open()
            Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("sp_test", oConn)
            cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date1
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date2
            Dim daData As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            daData.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            oConn.Close()
        End Try
End Function
```

But it's shown all the `Produccts`, so how can I get only `Product 1` in result from stored procedure?

Comment: Best choice is to pass another parameter. And you should avoid prefixing your procedures with `sp_`. Prefixing is not a best practice at all, but `sp_` is a bad one for sure.

Comment: thanks for advice :)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4):

I seriously hope don't have `SELECT *` in production. It's a big no-no for SQL coding.

In VB.net, you can filter for rows that satisfy a condition with the [`SELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim rows[] as DataRow = dt.Select("Product = 'Product 1'")
```

---

If you want to do the filtering in SQL before it hits the VB.net layer, change your command text to:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    Product     varchar(100),
    Qty         int
)

INSERT INTO #tmp (Product, Quantity)
    EXEC sp_test @date1, @date2

SELECT Product, Quantity FROM #tmp
WHERE Product = 'Product 1'
```

And remove the `cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure` line.

Comment: Just like I said, it's only a sample, and I've try this, but still execute all the products.

Comment: I assume you can't change the stored procedure? Your SQL command will have to be a lot longer if you want to filter the data before hitting the `DataTable`.

Comment: uumm.. I think wrapping my union with select just like ARich and Jeroen answers is what I'm looking for. But, thanks for your fast answer :)

Comment: Different solutions for different constraints you face

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your union'ed query into another select statement and make the union'ed query a sub-select like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM
(
SELECT a, b, c FROM Tb1
UNION ALL
SELECT a, b, c FROM Tb2
)
AS Tb3
WHERE a = 'something'
```

This will ONLY select the rows where the value in column named a is equal to 'something'. It doesn't matter if that was in the first or second because the `WHERE` clause is actually operating on the alias Tb3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), but couldn't you wrap your unions with a select and use a third parameter to filter the results? Something like this maybe:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
 @date1  datetime,
 @date2  datetime,
 @product varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 select P.Product, 
        --other columns here
 from (
       select 'Product 1' as Product, * from tab1 where dateStart = @date1 and dateEnd = @date2 and qty >= 100
       union all
       select 'Product 2' as Product, * from tab2 where dateStart = @date1 and dateEnd = @date2 and qty < 100
      ) P
 where P.Product = @product
END
```

Then in your [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) you'd add a parameter like this:

```
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date1
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date2
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@product", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "Product 1"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I already said, however I had not considered the possibility @codedifferent puts forward which is that the OP might not be able to change the stored proc.

Comment: @Jeroen You'll notice we posted at exactly the same time...if the OP can't modify the spr then the OP will tell us. Until then this approach can be considered a valid solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jeroen You guys posted at exactly the same time just like ARich said, and both are the answers that I'm looking for.

Comment: @ARich we are awesome :-)